# How to display only different rows using diff (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, diff

How can I display only different rows using diff in a separate file?

For example, the file number 1 contains the line:

```
1;john;125;3
1;tom;56;2
2;jack;10;5
```

A file number 2 contains the following lines:

```
1;john;125;3
1;tom;58;2
2;jack;10;5
```

How to make in the following happen?

```
1;tom;58;2
```

Comment: What should happen to `1;tom;56;2`? Should the second file always have priority? What should happen if the first file contain a line not in the second file?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

a.txt:

```
1;john;125;3
1;tom;56;2
2;jack;10;5
```

b.txt:

```
1;john;125;3
1;tom;58;2
2;jack;10;5
```

Use [comm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm):

```
comm -13 a.txt b.txt 
1;tom;58;2
```

The command line options to `comm` are pretty straight-forward:

> -1       suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
>
> -2       suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
>
> -3        suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)

Comment: Yes, noticed that - I assumed the first file to have priority. Have updated the post

Comment: "Note that the comm command expects the two files to be in sorted order."

Comment: Also note that comm does not imply `uniq` so in case a line is present multiple times in file1 and only once in file2, each additional occurrence in file1 will be listed as a difference by `comm` (which it of course is...).

Answer (score 21):

Here's a simple solution that I think is better than `diff`:

`sort file1 file2 | uniq -u`

- `sort file1 file2` concatenates the two files and sorts it
- `uniq -u` prints the unique lines (that do not repeat). It requires the input to be pre-sorted.

Comment: underrated answer! Simple and elegant, deals with the sorting issue and uses the impeccably named uniq utility

Comment: But wouldn't this output both?
1;tom;56;2
1;tom;58;2

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you want to retain only the lines unique to file 2 you can do:

```
comm -13 file1 file2
```

Note that the `comm` command expects the two files to be in sorted order.

Answer (score 7):

Using group format specifiers you can suppress printing of unchanged lines and print only changed lines for changed

`diff --changed-group-format="%>" --unchanged-group-format="" file1 file2`

Comment: This works great for strings too using <(echo "$string1") <(echo "$string2")

Answer (score 0):

The following command provides only differences of two files one line at a time :

```
diff -W 400 -ay --suppress-common-lines <(nl file1) <(nl file2) | sed 's/|'"$(printf '\t')"'\+ \+/\n/g' | sed 's/^'"$(printf '\t')"'* */\n/g' | grep -aE '[0-9]'
```

It displayed the location of the difference and juste the lines which are different. the -W 400 should be adjusted to the max length of line of both files.
The -a is not mandatory but it is really useful in case of text files which are recognized as binary by the system.